# Windows Forms NotifyIcon disappers randomly in WPF application

Tags: wpf, windows, notifyicon

I have a WPF application that consists of a long running main window. 
In the MainWindow constructor a define and initialize my notifyIcon as follows.

```
 notifyIcon = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon();
                if (File.Exists(logoFile))
                {
                    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(logoFile, UriKind.Absolute));
                    this.Icon = image;
                    notifyIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(logoFile);
                    this.gridAbout_imgLogo.Source = image;
                }
                else
                {
                    using (Stream iconStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/APP;component/Resources/Logo.ico")).Stream)
                    {
                        System.Drawing.Icon defaultIcon = new System.Drawing.Icon(iconStream);
                        notifyIcon.Icon = defaultIcon;
                        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/APP;component/Resources/Logo.ico"));
                        this.Icon = image;
                        this.gridAbout_imgLogo.Source = image;
                    }
                }
                if (config != null)
                    notifyIcon.Text = config.app_name;
                else
                    notifyIcon.Text = "APP";
                notifyIcon.DoubleClick += notifyIcon_DoubleClick;
                notifyIcon.Visible = true;
                System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu m = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
                System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem mi = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
                mi.Text = "Show App Status";
                mi.Click += (s, e) => ShowApplication();
                m.MenuItems.Add(mi);

# if DEBUG
                System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem mi1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();
                mi1.Text = "Exit";
                mi1.Click += (s, e) => Application.Current.Shutdown();
                m.MenuItems.Add(mi1);
# endif

                notifyIcon.ContextMenu = m;
```

Sometimes notify icon simply disappeears from the tray. No code such as nofityIcon.Visible = false.
When I check the task manager I can see my app is running.

Are there other reasons for flaky NotifyIcon behavior, as well as remedies?

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the Notification Icon settings in System Tray. ControlPanel-> Notification Area Icons -> Check the Checkbox 'Always show all Icons' (Windows 7).

Comment: Yes, I have checked all the Icons. The Icon is missing.

Comment: 1. Does the Icon appear on starting the application. 2. Can you tell me what action makes the icon invisible, double click, right mouse click? 3. Does logoFile exists?

Comment: Yes athe icon appears on the starting of the App. I couldn't figure out when its getting disappeared but disappears randomly. Yes the logofile exisit. From an another post I understood that initialization of notifyicon one different thread than UI leads to similar error. Unfortunately, that was also my case. Now, I have changed the logic so that it will initialized only on main UI thread. Lets see how its goes !